# One INSERT with multiple SELECT

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, sql-insert, common-table-expression, sql-returning

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426967/adding-two-select-statements-into-one-insert-into-statement-in-postgresql), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791061/postgres-insert-into-with-two-select-statements) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736732/update-or-insert-multiple-rows-and-columns-from-subquery-in-postgresql), but I cant make this SQL work:

```
INSERT INTO main_phrase (description) VALUES ('Mot commun féminin pluriel animaux');
/* ERROR: */
WITH
  t1 AS (
    SELECT id 
    FROM main_phrase 
    WHERE description='Mot commun féminin pluriel animaux'
  ),
  t2 AS (
    SELECT id 
    FROM main_groupecategories 
    WHERE description='Mot commun féminin pluriel animaux'
  )
INSERT 
  INTO main_phrasegroupecategories (phrase_id, groupe_categories_id)
  VALUES                           (t1.id,     t2.id);
```

I get:

> ERROR: missing entry for the clause FROM for table t1

What am I missing?

Comment: Please *always* declare your version of Postgres. Providing your current code is very helpful, but there should also be a plain English description of what you are trying to achieve. And table definitions should be there, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Assumptions

- You want to link the newly inserted row in `main_phrase` to the row(s) in `main_groupecategories` with the same `description`.
- `main_phrase.id` is a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column.

#### Explanation for Error

You cannot refer to any tables (including CTE) in a free-standing `VALUES` expression, you would have to use `SELECT` with a `FROM` clause. But there is a better solution. See below.

#### Better Query

Use a [data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) instead to make the whole operation shorter, safer and faster:

```
WITH p AS (
   INSERT INTO main_phrase (description)
   VALUES ('Mot commun féminin pluriel animaux')  -- provide description once
   RETURNING id, description  -- and reuse it further down
   )
INSERT INTO main_phrasegroupecategories (phrase_id, groupe_categories_id)
SELECT p.id, g.id
FROM   p
JOIN   main_groupecategories g USING (description);
```

If you want to use any values of the new rows, have them returned immediately with another `RETURNING` clause to the second `INSERT`.

Why would you have the same `description` redundantly in both tables of your (presumed) [many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)? Might be a problem in your database design.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL multi INSERT...RETURNING with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775109/postgresql-multi-insert-returning-with-multiple-columns/22775268#22775268)
- [SELECT * FROM NEW TABLE equivalent in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580491/select-from-new-table-equivalent-in-postgres/26580960#26580960)
- [Combining INSERT statements in a data-modifying CTE with a CASE expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992241/combining-insert-statements-in-a-data-modifying-cte-with-a-case-expression/28993466#28993466)

Comment: It's not a problem in my design: phrase = sentence in english. All the words are sorted into groups many categories and i need to generate sentences based only on the "groups of categories" (to generate funny sentences). but sometimes there's only one word left "alone" so I need a sentence = phrase that has only the "groups of categories" this word belongs to, so I can still make something with this word.

Comment: This syntax is very new to me, and I feel like it's very powerful, but it's overkill when you want to do such simple daily operations. Thank you very much indeed for your help!

Comment: Looking at the various possible SQL statements, it seems to be the *simplest* possible way to me - other advantages aside.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've started actually adding the word "erwin" to my searches for pgsql questions, so I get a good answer.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO main_phrase (phrase_id, groupe_categories_id) 
WITH
  t1 AS (
    SELECT id 
    FROM main_phrase 
    WHERE description='Mot commun féminin pluriel animaux'
  ),
  t2 AS (
    SELECT id 
    FROM main_groupecategories 
    WHERE description='Mot commun féminin pluriel animaux'
  )
  select t1.id, t2.id
  from t1,t2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried the following statement in PG and it worked.

```
INSERT INTO main_phrase (phrase_id, groupe_categories_id)
 SELECT
     (SELECT id FROM main_phrase WHERE description='Mot commun féminin pluriel animaux'),
     (SELECT id FROM main_groupecategories WHERE description='Mot commun féminin pluriel animaux');
```